# Define Writer Functor

Tags: haskell, functor

Given any category *C* with products and an object *c* in *C*, we can define a functor _ × *c* : *C* -> *C* which maps an object *a* to *a* × *c* and a morphism *f* : *a* -> *b* to *f* × *id<sub>c</sub>* : *a* × *c* -> *b* × *c*.

I would like to implement such a functor in Haskell. I would like *c* to be `String`, so that the functor passes along logs.

I tried the following:

```
type Writer a = (a,String)

instance Functor Writer where    
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> Writer a -> Writer b.   
  fmap f (x,s) = (f x, s)
```

However, I am getting an error which says "The type synonym ‘Writer’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none."

Comment: The tuple `(,) String` is already such a writer. To make your own instance you need to make it into a newtype: `newtype MyWriter a = W (a, String)`. You can derive all the instances via the original Writer monad: `deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad) via Writer String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You work witha  type synonym, and for a 2-tuple this is already defined.

You can define a new type and make a `Functor` instance for this:

```
data Writer a = Writer a String

instance Functor Writer where    
  fmap f (Writer x s) = Writer (f x) s
```